# How to Displaying Data in ListView or CollectionView with List in .NET MAUI using MVVM Architecture

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, mvvm, maui

I'm currently working on a .NET MAUI project and I'm trying to display data in either a ListView or a CollectionView. My application follows the MVVM architecture pattern, and I would like to know how to achieve this using a List.

Specifically, I have a List object that contains the data I want to display, but I'm not sure how to bind this data to either a ListView or a CollectionView in my XAML file. I want to ensure that the data is updated dynamically when changes occur in the underlying List.

Could someone please provide guidance on how to accomplish this? Any sample code or step by step instructions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of updates are you expecting? You can 1. change the list instance (get a new list of items and assign that list instance to the items property) or you can 2. modify the items in the list. On 1. just notify that the property has changed. On 2. you need an `ObservableCollection<T>` that will notify on any changes within that collection

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can read the official document about the [Data binding and MVVM in the maui](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/xaml/fundamentals/mvvm). It has the detailed steps about implementing the MVVM.

After that, you can refer to the official sample on the github about [CollectionView](https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/tree/main/7.0/UserInterface/Views/CollectionViewDemos/CollectionViewDemos) and [ListView](https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/tree/main/7.0/UserInterface/Views/ListViewDemos/ListViewDemos). The official demo contains the code about Model, ViewModel and Binding in the xaml.

Finally, you can use the [CommunityToolkit.Mvvm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/) package to get the MVVM work in the maui easily.